# CURL CouchDB Replication command - Invalid JSON

Tags: json, powershell, curl, couchdb, replication

I'm running the following line in curl trying to setup couchdb replication:

```
curl -X POST -d '{"source":"http://user:password@siteA.com:5984/main","target":"main"}' -H 'Content-Type: application/json' http://user:password@siteB.com/_replicate
```

It keeps returning the following error:

```
{"error":"bad_request","reason":"invalid UTF-8 JSON"}
```

As far as I can tell the JSON seems valid. Any ideas?

I'm also using Powershell as well.

Comment: An aside note. In your example it looks like you are passing as source the destination and as target the source.

Answer (score 7):

It happend many times to me as well. PowerShell parser (who knows why) removes quotes in the json.

So it sends it to curl like '{source:http://user:password@siteA.com:5984/main,target:main}'
You need to call it like this:

```
curl -X POST -d '{"""source""":"""http://user:password@siteA.com:5984/main""","""target""":"""main"""}' -H 'Content-Type: application/json' http://user:password@siteB.com/_replicate
```

Look at http://pscx.codeplex.com/ module. `EchoArgs` might help when discovering such problems.

Answer (score 2):

Looking at the CouchDB wiki I found [this](http://wiki.apache.org/couchdb/Quirks_on_Windows#Run) which could be useful to solve your issue.
Basically under Windows you need to escape special characters or to write the JSON in a file and use that from the curl CLI.

Answer (score 0):

I've had problems with curl and PowerShell before - my resolution was to call it from a batch file (the output put into a PowerShell variable)... thought it might be related to the way arguments were passed to curl being misinterpreted - I never got to the bottom of it as this worked...

maybe this could help http://huddledmasses.org/the-problem-with-calling-legacy-or-native-apps-from-powershell/

Answer (score 0):

In order not to write all the json part manually, as you use powershell, you should try [PSCouchDB](https://github.com/MatteoGuadrini/PSCouchDB).

Replicas as well:

```
PS >using module PSCouchDB
PS >$rep = New-Object PSCouchDBReplication -ArgumentList 'main','main_rep'
PS >$rep.SetContinuous()
PS >New-CouchDBReplication -Data $rep -Authorization "admin:password"
```

reference: https://pscouchdb.readthedocs.io/en/latest/server.html#create-replica